# How to get list of elements which is visible when any link is being clicked in the new tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a link called "See all the 40 employees on LinkedIn" so when i click this it is opening a new tab where it is showing all the 40 people list with there details individually one after another, so i want to get the total number of employees, so how do i do this, any help would be appreciated. Below is the code snippet.

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("employees on LinkedIn").click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Image Link:

[image]

```
List <WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.className(("search-results__list")));
list.size();
```

I have tried here to get the size but it always return 1. Image Link:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are locating `ul` thats why it returns only single element. All required details are under `<li>` so you should locate `li` tags.

Change your code to this:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".search-results__list > li")
```